# Xcode 6 Launch Screen file creating issues?

Tags: iphone, upload, ios8, xcode6, launch

I have to update apps for iOS8 & the new iPhone6/iPhone6 Plus.
These apps are meant to support all iPhones & iPads running on iOS8, iOS7 & iOS6.

I have updated them using Xcode 6 and have added a Launch-Screen-File instead of Launch-Images I had used for the iOS7 update last year.

While trying to upload on to the App Store via Application Loader 3.0, an error comes up:
"Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5". It tell me to include Launch Images as well.

So what could be the issue? - I read in a post that iOS6 and/or iOS7 doesn't support Launch-Screen-File.

Comment: if you want to support iOS7, etc - you have to use Launch-Images

Comment: you have to add launch image in Image Asset. and support image asset - Launch image for iOS 6 and Prior. it will work..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

“In iOS 8 and later, you can create a XIB or storyboard file instead of a static launch image” - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html

To support iOS7 and below you have to use Launch images: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconMatrix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH27-SW2

Comment: Hi TonyMkenu, thanks for your help.....I just added launch images, including for iPhone5 with the '-568h' modifier.....then tried to upload again, but it still gives the same error - "Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5"

Comment: Modify your project to use those images (not LauchScreen.xib)

Comment: Yeah I had to select my LaunchImage in the General tab of Targets in Launch-Images-Source....it got uploaded thanks! :)

Comment: WTH? We can't use Launch Screen File in iOS 7?